# How to use Android ARCore without arsceneview

Tags: android, arcore

Is there a way to get my camera pose or the mobile device position in space without having to use ARSceneView. I am not displaying the camera stream or a 3D render.

I currently get my camera pose from:

```
val camera = arSceneView.arFrame?.camera
val pose = camera.pose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AR session (com.google.ar.core.Session) to get the pose:

```
val session = Session(this@MainActivity)
```

Then to get the pose, update the session:

```
val frame = session.update()
val pose = frame.camera.pose;
```

Comment: When I try doing this I get a 'MissingGlContextException' and it seems like OpenGL is a view. Do you have a wider example of how I could get a the camera pose without a view?

Comment: samuigohan do you have a working example, any more details you can provide would be super helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: So sorry for the late answer. I am using GLSurfaceView to render objects. [Here](https://programmer.help/blogs/arcore-quick-start-drawing-3d-models-using-glsurfaceview-and-arcore.html) is an intro on how to use it. If you need more help with this, I will be quicker to answer next time.